# How to delete branch with all commits pushed to wrong repository?

Tags: git, commit, history

We have several git repositories working on Android projects. We have 'boot' repo which is small and 'android' which is huge. During development one of our guys pushed branch from 'android' to 'boot' and now boot repository size is 700 MB! Is there anyway to completely delete the wrong branch and all commits related to it from 'boot' now?

I tried filter-branch and other methods, but most of them change commit numbers made after that wrong push

In theory this shouldn't be a problem delete commits which are 'on the side'. This branch was never merged to 'master' and these commit are not parents to any useful commits

Answer (score 15):

Deleting a branch from a remote server is done using `git push`

```
git push --delete boot branchname
```

After this each person can run the following command on their local repo to remove the deleted branch.

```
git remote prune boot
```

After the branch is removed though, the data will still linger in each repository for 2-4 weeks by default as a measure to prevent accidental data loss. If the disk space concern is really that important to you, then it can be removed sooner but take note that this will remove all unreachable objects that are being kept temporarily to prevent accidental data loss.

```
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

Answer (score 5):

Deleting the branch is done by

```
git branch -D branch_name
```

Note the capital `-D` option: this tells git to delete the branch even if it's not fully merged into master.

After doing that, fire up the garbage collector with `git gc`. Then, you should be fine.

Comment: The branch itself is just a name for a commit. (40 bytes on disk) and deleting the branch cannot solve m problem. The objects created by incorrect push are still referenced in the repository by a lot of commits pushed to the repository so GC doesn't help either

Comment: this is not an answer to the original question. The data of the original commit still exists.